# How to use compass with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, compass-sass

I have searched and searched and all I could see was that to use compass with rails 3.1 was to just edit the Gemfile like so:

```
gem 'compass', :git => 'https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git', :branch => 'rails31'
gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
```

Yes I understand that but what next? Every tutorial I saw said just that, use that certain fork. But I am still having trouble with using compass with rails 3.1.

I did this:

```
$ compass init rails . --syntax sass
  directory ./app/stylesheets/ 
  create ./config/compass.rb 
  create ./app/stylesheets/screen.sass 
  create ./app/stylesheets/print.sass 
  create ./app/stylesheets/ie.sass
```

And since 3.1 was using assets now, I just transferred all those files to 3.1. Also, I am using compass-960 plugin, so where do I require it? I tried adding a compass.rb with require 960 and require html5-boilerplate and I still keep getting errors:

```
Error compiling asset application.css:
NoMethodError: undefined method `Error' for Compass:Module
  (in /Users/eumir/rails_apps/kiseki/app/assets/stylesheets/screen.sass)

NoMethodError (undefined method `Error' for Compass:Module
(in /Users/eumir/rails_apps/kiseki/app/assets/stylesheets/screen.sass)):
```

I tried doing compass compile and it gave me this:

$ compass compile
     Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
     Run "compass -h" to get help.

As I said, I already edited my compass.rb so I am still stumped as to how to go about with this. Any help?

Comment: not sure, but i don't think it works yet on 3.1 without a boatload of hacks

Comment: I successfully upgraded my app today (it uses compass) - documented it [here](http://webtempest.com/upgrade-rails-3-to-3-1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solutions in the other answers are deprecated with the latest version of Compass, v0.12, which requires an adapter to work with a rails app. The Compass author, Chris Eppstein, has put installation instructions on github:
**https://github.com/compass/compass-rails**

This adapter supports rails versions 2.3 and greater

Comment: I tested this out but it seems it is buggy for rails 3.1.0

Comment: yup, it was confirmed by scott when i created an issue. it works on rails 3.1.3, not 3.1.0. some legacy problem with sprockets i think

Answer (score 33):

**UPDATE**: Seems like there is a better way !
Source: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/07/12/sass-sprockets-compass-with-rails-3-1/

**UPDATE 2**(dec 2, 2011): Chris Eppstein, creator of Compass posted this Github Gist of how to integrate Compass with Rails 3.1: https://gist.github.com/1184843

I now prefer this method over mine, as I noticed a great speed improvement at compilation time when using livereload.

---

**MY METHOD:**
(I now consider it deprecated, but maybe it can be useful in some cases, so here it is for reference:)

First, in your Gemfile, add:

```
gem "compass", "~> 0.12.alpha.0"
```

And don’t forget to execute a

```
bundle update
```

Then, in config/application.rb:

```
config.generators.stylesheet_engine = :sass
```

Rename application.css.scss to application.css.sass, or create it, and replace its contents by:

```
@import compass
@import _blueprint
```

(If you want to keep the new Rails 3.1 manifest code at the beginning of the stylesheet, you’ll have to replace the ‘/* */’ comments by the sass-syntax version ‘//’ at the beginning of each line)

Now, to test if compass and blueprint mixins work, add some code to the same file application.css.sass:

```
@import compass
@import _blueprint
body
  background: black
  +linear-gradient(color-stops(white, black))
  +column(5)
```

Run your rails server with

```
bundle exec rails server
```

Load your app in a browser, and visit http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css

If everything went well, you should see the compiled code.

**Source:**

http://blog.pixarea.com/2011/07/using-compass-blueprint-semantic-and-sass-syntax-in-rails-3-1/

Comment: Updated my answer to use compass gem version '0.12.alpha.0' instead of branch 'rails31'

Comment: updated my answer: there is a new better way, see the provided link.

Comment: there's another better way as chris eppstein from compass now posted how to integrate compass to 3.1: https://gist.github.com/1184843

Comment: hope you dont mind me updating your answer :) I added the link to chris' gist

Answer (score 1):

Peter Gumeson from the compass users groups pointed me to a fix for this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/compass-users/mU5HBt8TCIg/2Rt7iSESTSAJ

Here's his message:

> Hi gang.  This github issue might help out.
>   https://github.com/sporkd/compass-html5-boilerplate/issues/19
>
> I am pretty much running everything on edge right now.  So my gemfile
>   looks something like this:
>
> ```
> gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
> gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.1.0.rc2'
> gem 'haml', :git => 'git://github.com/nex3/haml.git'
> gem 'haml-rails'
> gem "compass", :git => "git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git", :tag => "0.12.alpha.0"
> gem 'compass-html5', :git => 'git://github.com/sporkd/compass-html5.git'
> ```
>
> I'm working on the rails generators right now, so it should not be too
>   far off.  But this should at least get you going.
>
> Peter

*changed branches as said by choonkeat

Comment: branch `rails31` disappeared. try `gem "compass", :git => "git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git", :tag => "0.12.alpha.0"` instead. for now.

Comment: `:tag => "0.12.alpha.0"` didn't work for me, but
`:tag => "v0.12.alpha.0"` did

Answer (score 0):

YOu can download the compass directory, dump it in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` so your directory structure is `vendor/assets/stylesheets/compass` Then from your main application stylesheets include the compass mixins ass required `@include compass/reset;`

Comment: it doesn't work using Rails 3.1 rc6 importing it from application.scss under app/assets/stylesheets