# Error compiling CSS asset (Compass + Sass + Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, compass-sass

I have a site running on Heroku using Compass with Saas an is working fine (compiling assets when pushing to Heroku seems to be fine).

I added a new folder inside assets to namespace other styling, like this

```
/app/assets/stylesheets/site/site1.css
/app/assets/stylesheets/site/site2.css
/app/assets/stylesheets/site/common/base.css.saas
/app/assets/stylesheets/site/site/site1.css.saas
/app/assets/stylesheets/site/site/site2.css.saas
...
```

The problem is when I visit a page that use `site1.css` styling I get the following error

```
Error compiling CSS asset
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: ../compass/css3/text-shadow.
Load path: /app
  (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/site/common/base.css.sass)

  /app/app/assets/stylesheets/site/common/base.css.sass)
```

The line that the error refers is this

```
/app/assets/stylesheets/site/common/base.css.sass
@import "../compass/css3/text-shadow"
```

I tried both `"../compass/css3/text-shadow"` and `"compass/css3/text-shadow"`. In both cases I got the same error.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using a --watch command? If so can you include that in your question? Also are you watching the directory or the individual file?

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why are you using .css.sass for your extension instead of using .scss?

Comment: @Kris what is the purpose of watch command and where should be used?

Comment: I prefer the older syntax without brackets.

Comment: I am not super familiar with how Heroku's environment is set up. But in order to compile your SASS to CSS their should be a watch command to watch your SASS file. Everytime you update your SASS file it will compile and output as CSS...

Comment: So what version of SASS are you using then? The older version I am assuming?

Comment: Here is an example of the SASS watch command... http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html, my guess is the path in your watch command is incorrect. I am assuming Heroku has a config file or something where that is set up.

Comment: sass  is 3.1 and compass 0.12.2, anyways I uses sass through sass-rails (3.2.5). I'm not familiar with any --watch command. Assets a precompiled automatically when deployed. Not sure what are you referring to.

Comment: Okay well based off the error it is most likely and issue with your path or something is off with your version of SASS and Compass... Take a look at this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480124/how-to-use-compass-with-rails-3-1

Comment: I don't see how that thread is related to this question. All gems I have installed are the newest version. current sass installed version is 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I needed to specify on `production.rb` file the additional files to compile

```
config.assets.precompile +=
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/site/site/*.*"].collect {|s| "site/" + File.basename(s).gsub(/.scss|.sass/, '') }
```

Now is working fine.